# MySQL GROUP BY and SELECT GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

This are my tables

**Products:**
[image]

**Orders**

[image]

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    orders.*, 
    IF (orders.price_type = 1, products.price * orders.quantity, products.discount_price * orders.quantity) AS subtotal
FROM
    orders
LEFT JOIN
    products
ON
    orders.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY 
    order_id
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you notice subtotal, it is only calculated depends on selected rows. How I can add those result of other rows with the same `order_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent' tested this, but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    orders.*, 
    sum(IF (orders.price_type = 1, products.price * orders.quantity, products.discount_price * orders.quantity)) AS subtotal
FROM
    orders
LEFT JOIN
    products
ON
    orders.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY 
    order_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this solution. It still returns the same number of rows, but it will surely give the total for each order_id, but with the rest of the columns related to only one of the order lines. But if it is accepted, who am i to say otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want the subtotal, i assume that you want only to calculate the value for each line of the orders table. To get that you have to remove the `DISTINCT` and the `GROUP BY`. (`DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are a little weird done together for something like this, and if you want every row to be returned with the subtotal, you don't need them):

```
SELECT orders.*, 
    IF(orders.price_type = 1,
        products.price * orders.quantity, 
        products.discount_price * orders.quantity) AS subtotal
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.id
```

This will get you the subtotal for every line in the orders table.

If you want the results `GROUPED BY order_id`, you can't really do `SELECT *` since the GROUP BY will make wrong assumptions about the other columns and you end up with wrong results, like you experienced. you can do:

```
SELECT orders.order_id,
       orders.order_date, 
       SUM(IF(orders.price_type = 1,
            products.price * orders.quantity, 
            products.discount_price * orders.quantity)) AS subtotal
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY orders.order_id, orders.order_date
```